# SQL Server: Accessing transactional data in nested triggers

Tags: sql-server, triggers, nested

I have the following setup in Ms SQL Server

### TableA

Id      uniqueidentified

Status  nvarchar ('Unknown', 'InProgress', 'Completed')

Other columns...

### TableB

Id      uniqueidentified

LastModifiedDate Date

Other columns...

TableA has an Update trigger that changes the LastModifiedDate on TableB every time there is a change in TableA

TableB has a trigger that puts a message into an SSB Queue every time LastModifiedDate is changed.

Question: How do I modify the trigger for TableB in such way that it will fire only when the Status of Table is Completed.

The challenge is that during the modification of Status in TableA the trigger caused in TableB doesn’t have access to the latest value of tableA (e.g. Completed)

I am not interested in:
  1) adding another column to TableB that will be modified by TriggerA when Status == complete 
  2) using a global temp table.

Is there another clever way to do this? (e.g. read the "updated" value of TriggerA while in the nested TriggerB)

Comment: Are these instead of update or after update triggers? if they are after update triggers, you should have access to the latest value of table A from table B

Answer (score 0):

Due to the transactional nature of things they are update triggers. After update triggers would indeed simplify the whole scenario but will be prone to get TableA and TableB out of sync. The only reasonable solution I found so far is to filter out trigger for TableB when TableA status is not "Complete" and add a 3rd trigger on TableA that would replicate TableB trigger when the status changes to Completed. Its not elegant as I wish and duplicates code.